# Sou novato e estou com problemas para executar meu programa corretamente! Help

Tags: c

Meu codigo tem que fazer o seguinte:

```
Escreva um programa que receba do usuário 4 nomes (nome1, nome2, nome3, nome4) e 4 salários (sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4) de funcionários de uma empresa. Exiba na tela a média (med) e o desvio padrão (s) dos salários. A equação que descreve o desvio padrão está listada a seguir:

Onde:
```

x_i é a amostra na posição i;
x ́ é a média aritmética das amostras;
né o número de amostras.

Ele compila e abre, mas a função do segundo scanf é pulada, e há problemas na captação dos dados tambem, Segue o codigo:

```
//bibliotecas
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
//inicio da funcao main
int main ()
{
    //declaracao de variaveis
    char nome1, nome2, nome3, nome4 [50];
    float sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4, media, desvio;

    //captacao, calculo e mostra dos dados
    printf ("\nDigite os nomes dos quatro funcionarios: ");
    scanf (" %c %c %c %c ", &nome1, &nome2, &nome3, &nome4);
    printf ("\nFoneca seus salarios, respectivamente: ");
    scanf (" %f %f %f %f ", &sal1, &sal2, &sal3, &sal4);
    media= (sal1+sal2+sal3+sal4)/4;
    printf ("\nA media aritmetica desses salarios e: %f", media);
    desvio=sqrt ((pow(sal1-media,2)+pow(sal2-media,2)+pow(sal3-media,2)+pow(sal4-media,2))/(4-1));
    printf ("\nO desvio padrao dos salarios e: %f", desvio);
    system ("pause");
}
```

===============================================================

Código att depois do primeiro comentário:

```
//bibliotecas
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
//inicio da funcao main
int main ()
{
    //declaracao de variaveis
    char nome1 [20], nome2 [20], nome3 [20], nome4 [20];
    float sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4, media, desvio;

    //captacao, calculo e mostra dos dados
    printf ("\n\aDigite os nomes dos quatro funcionarios: ");
    scanf (" %s %s %s %s ", nome1, nome2, nome3, nome4);
    printf ("\n\aFoneca seus salarios, respectivamente: ");
    scanf (" %f %f %f %f ", &sal1, &sal2, &sal3, &sal4);
    media= (sal1+sal2+sal3+sal4)/4;
    printf ("\n\aA media aritmetica desses salarios e: %f", media);
    desvio=sqrt ((pow(sal1-media,2)+pow(sal2-media,2)+pow(sal3-media,2)+pow(sal4-media,2))/(4-1));
    printf ("\n\aO desvio padrao dos salarios e: %f", desvio);
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Com %c no scanf você está lendo um único caractere e não uma string de caracteres. Para ler uma string utilize %s e não coloque o & antes do nome do array. Em sua declaração você deve colocar a quantidade de caracteres em cada um dos nomes e não apenas no último.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu concertei tudo isso que disse! Mas o problema principal ainda persiste. O segundo scanf não é executado, é pulado de uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Jackson,

O problema do seu programa está no uso do `scanf` com esse tipo de dado. o scanf lê a string até encontrar um espaço, um enter ou uma tabulação, ou seja: " ", "\n" ou "\t".

Existem algumas soluções pra o seu problema:

Primeiro que não pude deixar de notar que o seu programa não faz absolutamente nada com os nomes que ele lê. então a primeira solução seria criar um grande vetor pra armazenar os nomes e usar a função `gets()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
char vetorNomes[100];

printf("Digite os nomes dos funcionarios: ");
gets(vetorNomes);
```

O que acontece aqui é que a função `gets()` lê TODOS os caracteres até encontrar um "Enter", ou seja: "\n".

Caso você precise armazenar os nomes em variáveis diferentes para operações futuras você pode criar variáveis separadamente e usar o `gets()` em cada uma delas.

**Exemplo:**

```
char nomeFuncionario1 [20], nomeFuncionario2 [20], nomeFuncionario3 [20], 
nomeFuncionario4 [20];

printf("Digite os nomes dos funcionarios: ");
gets(nomeFuncionario1);
gets(nomeFuncionario2);
gets(nomeFuncionario3);
gets(nomeFuncionario4);
```

E por último, mas não menos importante, você pode declarar seu tipo de dado no `scanf` como `%[^\n]`. `%[]` é um tipo de dado que lê uma cadeia de caracteres, e a sintaxe "^\n" serve pra apontar que, ao se deparar com um Enter, a leitura acabou.

Exemplo:

```
char nomeFuncionario1 [20], nomeFuncionario2 [20], nomeFuncionario3 [20], 
nomeFuncionario4 [20];

printf ("\n\aDigite os nomes dos quatro funcionarios: ");
scanf("%[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n] %[^\n]", nomeFuncionario1, nomeFuncionario2, 
nomeFuncionario3, nomeFuncionario4);
```

Vai funcionar da mesma forma que o exemplo de `gets()` acima.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!